# Send Email After Button Click in ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi i am trying to send am email after Button click in Asp.net.

The emails to send the email to will be retrieved from a query.

```
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlDataReader reader;
        string sendMessage = "SELECT aspnet_Membership.Email FROM aspnet_Membership join User_Profile on User_Profile.UserId = aspnet_Membership.UserId JOIN Project_List on Project_List.ProfileId = User_Profile.ProfileId WHERE Project_List.ProfileId = 1";

        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sendMessage, myConnection);



            ArrayList emailArray = new ArrayList();
            reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();


            while (reader.Read())
            {
                emailArray.Add(reader["email"]);
            }

            foreach (string email in emailArray)
```

it doesn't come up with any errors, and i don't receive any emails

Comment: Is a certificate present at the server for the SSL connection?

Comment: no, no certificate is present

Comment: Does the SMTP server have a log you can access? It might provide a clue, e.g. that it respectfully declines to relay email with your specified "from" address.

Comment: So why did you include `smtpclient.EnableSsl = true;` How do you expect it to work? Read the Remarks section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and add an exception handler

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd this setting is reauqiered for google smtp.

Comment: Then a certificate should be present according to the MSDN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work:

```
foreach(string email in emailArray)
{
     SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
     smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
     smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("tayyib@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxxx");
     smtp.EnableSsl = true;

     MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("tayyib@gmail.com", email); 
     msg.Subject = "Test1";
     msg.Body = "Test2";

     smtp.Send(msg);
 }
```

There is security setting which you should turn off in your gmail account.

**EDIT:** Like I said you should TURN OFF security setting in gmail account ! If this link doesn't help you just google the exception ! Check the [Link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1144110?hl=en) ! Or this [LINK](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

Comment: hi i am getting this error-----------Error 6 The type or namespace name 'NetworkCredential' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: using System.Net.Mail?

Comment: @CarterWillams Man if you can't add a reference ... using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail; If you click on the class and stay 2-3 seconds little dash will be shown under the class ! Use this to add references !

Comment: Thanks, i got this error----The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at-----and an email from google saying sign in attempt blocked

Comment: one last question, can i include a sender name?

Comment: Check Sender property of MailMessage I'm not sure if this is what you want.